# In java, How would I make a new button appear without minimizing my interface

Tags: java

Every time i click a button a new button is suppose appear, but it's not appearing after i press it unless i minimize the window and then open it again. heres my code for the GUI: 
P.S. i was playing around with the code just in case your wondering about the variables.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame{
private Label Count;
private JTextField tfCount;
private Button btnCount;

public Gui(){
    super("counter Gui");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    Count = new Label("Box Maker");
    add(Count);

    tfCount = new JTextField(10);
    tfCount.setEditable(true);
    add(tfCount);

    btnCount = new Button("Enter");
    add(btnCount);

    potatoHandler handler = new potatoHandler();
    btnCount.addActionListener(handler);
    tfCount.addActionListener(handler);
}
private class potatoHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String s = "";
        if (event.getSource() == tfCount || event.getSource() == btnCount){
            Button newButton = new Button("new Button");
            add(newButton);

        }


    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container you added the button to

```
private class potatoHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String s = "";
        if (event.getSource() == tfCount || event.getSource() == btnCount){
            Button newButton = new Button("new Button");
            add(newButton);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you So much! i'm still a begginer but i hope to get better

Comment: It's a gotcha that most people fall over